# How to access Laravel Aliases?

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a small application from scratch to understand how Laravel works and I don't understand how `aliases` works.

My `index.php` is currently pretty simple:

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(dirname(__DIR__));
dd($app);
```

Now I would like to access one alias such as `request` so I have added:

```
dd(app('request'));
```

But I get an error, request is not found:

```
Illuminate/Container/Container.php(780): ReflectionClass->__construct('request')
```

However I found in `Illuminate\Foundation\Application@registerCoreContainerAliases` that `request` should be loaded.

What did I miss?

I also tried to do this:

```
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->instance('request', $request);
dd($app->isAlias('request'));
```

And I get `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your own app instance you need to set it as the default container:

```
 Container::setInstance(new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(dirname(__DIR__)));
```

This way whenever you use `app(..)` you will be able to access your new instance's bindings and aliases. However, the aliases work in the opposite way from what you're testing.

For example:

```
 app()->isAlias('request'); // false
 app()->isAlias(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class); // true
 app()->getAlias(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class); // "request"
```

Note that the actual request is not initialized until `$kernel->handle` is called so doing `app('request')` will not work until the framework is actively handling a request.

The boilerplate code that creates the app is at [app.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/app.php) which is called from [index.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php)

The request instance is set in the [Kernel.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php#L142)